# Custom PHP Error Page for NGINX Not Responding To '?=_'

Tags: php, nginx

I've recently created a custom error page with configuration such as:

`error_page 404 /error.php?code=404`

But it seems to show up only `error.php` instead of `error.php?code=404`.

I've cheked the php file by accessing `/error.php?code=404` in my browser and it works fine. I am using $Get

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) it seems that you can specify only an URI of script name (or @named location), not its parameters. I guess the script receives the parameters of the original URI instead.

There are several solutions/workarounds:

1) You need to have a separate errorXYZ.php script for each error code you want to redirect.

2) Or use external redirect such as `http://yourserver.com/error.php?code=404`, but note that this will be defaut reply with HTTP response code 302 and the users will see the `error.php` location in their browser.

3) Or URIs such as `/error.php/404` and parse it inside your PHP script.